# HTML form doesn't work even though I added names

Tags: php, html, forms

I am making a form in HTML and I came across this error:

```
                <form action="/Profile/new/poll/posted" method="post">
                <input class="hover-edit h2 hor-center" id="title" title="Poll's title ('New Poll' is not allowed)" value="New Poll" style="position: relative;text-align: center;width:95%;margin-top:2%;">
                <hr>
                <p><label for="opt1">Option 1</label> <input type="radio" disabled class="option"><input type="text" class="hover-edit" style="margin-top:1%;margin-bottom:1%;" name="opt1" id="opt1" value="Option 1"> &nbsp; <button type="button">Disable</button></button></p>
                <p><label for="opt2">Option 2</label> <input type="radio" disabled class="option"><input type="text" class="hover-edit" style="margin-top:1%;margin-bottom:1%;" name="opt2" id="opt2" value="Option 2"> &nbsp; <button type="button">Disable</button></button></p>
                <p><label for="opt3">Option 3</label> <input type="radio" disabled class="option"><input type="text" class="hover-edit" style="margin-top:1%;margin-bottom:1%;" name="opt3" id="opt3" value="Option 3"> &nbsp; <button type="button">Disable</button></button></p>
                <p><label for="opt4">Option 4</label> <input type="radio" disabled class="option"><input type="text" class="hover-edit" style="margin-top:1%;margin-bottom:1%;" name="opt4" id="opt4" value="Option 4"> &nbsp; <button type="button">Disable</button></button></p>
                <p><label for="opt5">Option 5</label> <input type="radio" disabled class="option"><input type="text" class="hover-edit" style="margin-top:1%;margin-bottom:1%;" name="opt5" id="opt5" value="Option 5"> &nbsp; <button type="button">Disable</button></button></p>
                <button type="submit" class="signupbtn" style="margin:2%;width:96%;">Post</button>
            </form>
```

The code above has a form, some labels, and some text inputs with names. However, on the action page, none of them was defined. I tried looking at the $_POST but still nothing. More specifically, I used:

```
    $opt1 = $_POST["opt1"];
    $opt2 = $_POST["opt2"];
    $opt3 = $_POST["opt3"];
    $opt4 = $_POST["opt4"];
    $opt5 = $_POST["opt5"];
    echo $opt1;
    echo $opt2;
    echo $opt3;
    echo $opt4;
    echo $opt5;
```

But PHP returned a warning for each one of the lines in my code.

Comment: `var_dump($_POST); exit;` that will show you the entire POST data

Comment: Why are the fields disabled? there is your problem

Comment: @delboy1978uk The radio inputs are disabled. After them, there are some normal, enabled text inputs. Also, I tried var_dump. I almost never end up asking things here.

Comment: open the browsers web inspector network panel. load the page, fill in and post the form. examine the request headers and body to see what you sent to the page

Answer (score 0):

Disabled input elements in a form will never be submitted. as @delboy1978uk pointed out https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp

so instead of

```
<p><label for="opt1">Option 1</label> <input type="radio" disabled class="option"><input type="text" class="hover-edit" style="margin-top:1%;margin-bottom:1%;" name="opt1" id="opt1" value="Option 1"> &nbsp; <button type="button">Disable</button></button></p>
```

write

```
<p><label for="opt1">Option 1</label> <input type="radio" class="option hover-edit" style="margin-top:1%;margin-bottom:1%;" name="opt1" id="opt1" value="Option 1"/></p>
```

By the way I'm not sure I understand your code you have label then input(radio) then input(text) then button then a closing button tag.

If you open a tag with input you close with input `<input type="button"></input>` and if button you close with button `<button></button>` don't mix the two tags, it is not the same.

Comment: Sorry for being that confusing, but it's a radio input, then a text input, and a button to disable the text input. I also tried it wthout the radio input, without the <p> tag, without the button, and with GET method. Still, nothing. I will remake the document. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Do you have a visual sketch of how it looks like? What does the radio button do? And the text input? and the other button? The button to disable text do you have the script to achieve that?

Comment: Please correct your code and update your question with latest code as to closing button tag without its corresponding open tag.